# Should a Canadian working in the USA, invest in a 401k, Roth IRA, Traditional IRA, and/or RRSP?

Tags: canada, 401k, ira, roth-ira, rrsp

I have a cousin who is a Canadian citizen working in the USA, asking me about the Canadian RRSP.  However being an American I am more familiar with 401k, Roth IRA, and Traditional IRA.

1)  From googling this site, https://www.wealthsimple.com/en-ca/learn/what-is-rrsp, it seems that the RRSP is a form of Roth IRA for Canadians?

2)  To participate in an RRSP, must she live and work in Canada?

3)  Is this a good recommendation for a Canadian worker based in the USA: First take advantage of contributing to a USA employer 401k.  Next utilize a traditional or Roth IRA.  Lastly, if she returns to Canada to work, then participate in an RRSP?

4)  Any other gotchas in this situation as a Canadian working and living in the USA?

I believe her goal is to save for retirement and a home downpayment while reducing taxable income.